# How to pass the selected max and min price value to java script function inside of select tag in html?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a search form with select options. The options will have two values, But I want two select option for Max and Min price value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="budget_min" name="filter_budget_min" value="0" />
<select onchange="updatePriceLimit(this)"> 
  <option value="0">- Min -</option>
  <option value="100000">1Lac</option>
  <option value="200000">2lacs</option>
  <option value="300000">3lacs</option>
  <option value="400000">4lacs</option>
  <option value="500000">5lacs</option>
  <option value="600000">6lacs</option>
  <option value="700000">7lacs</option>
  <option value="800000">8lacs</option>
  <option value="900000">9lacs</option>
  <option value="1000000">10lacs</option>
  <option value="1100000">11lacs</option>
  <option value="1200000">12lacs</option>
  <option value="1300000">13lacs</option>
  <option value="5000000">50lacs</option>
  <option value="6000000">60lacs</option>
  <option value="7000000">70lacs</option>
  <option value="8000000">80lacs</option>
  <option value="9000000">90lacs</option>
  <option value="10000000">1cr</option>
</select>
<script>

function updatePriceLimit(select) {
var limit = select.value.split('0');
document.getElementById('budget_min').value = limit[0];

}
```

```
<select onchange="updatePriceLimit(this)"> 
  <option value="0">- Max -</option>
  <option value="100000">1Lac</option>
  <option value="200000">2lacs</option>
  <option value="300000">3lacs</option>
  <option value="400000">4lacs</option>
  <option value="500000">5lacs</option>
  <option value="600000">6lacs</option>
  <option value="700000">7lacs</option>
  <option value="800000">8lacs</option>
  <option value="900000">9lacs</option>
  <option value="1000000">10lacs</option>
  <option value="1100000">11lacs</option>
  <option value="1200000">12lacs</option>
  <option value="1300000">13lacs</option>
  <option value="5000000">50lacs</option>
  <option value="6000000">60lacs</option>
  <option value="7000000">70lacs</option>
  <option value="8000000">80lacs</option>
  <option value="9000000">90lacs</option>
  <option value="10000000">1cr</option>
</select>
<script>
function updatePriceLimit(select) {
var limit = select.value.split('1');

document.getElementById('budget_max').value = limit[1];
}
```

When I am using following code, it is working perfectly

```
<select onchange="updatePriceLimit(this)"> 
  <option value="0-0">- Price Range -</option>
  <option value="100000-1000000">Below 10 Lacs</option>
  <option value="1000000-3000000">10 Lacs - 30 lacs</option>
  <option value="3000000-6000000">30 Lacs - 60 Lacs</option>
  <option value="6000000-9000000">60 Lacs - 90 Lacs</option>
  <option value="9000000-12000000">90 Lacs - 1.20 Cr</option>
  <option value="12000000-15000000">1.20 Cr- 1.50 Cr</option>
  <option value="12000000-15000000">1.20 Cr - 1.50 Cr</option>
  <option value="15000000-20000000">1.50 Cr - 2 Cr</option>
  <option value="20000000-25000000">2 Cr - 2.5 Cr</option>
  <option value="25000000-30000000">2.5 Cr - 3 Cr</option>
  <option value="30000000-40000000">3 Cr - 4 Cr</option>
</select>

<script>
function updatePriceLimit(select) {
var limit = select.value.split('-');
document.getElementById('budget_min').value = limit[0];
document.getElementById('budget_max').value = limit[1];
}
```

Any ideas, please do me favor.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your script like this:

```
function updatePriceLimit(select,budget) {
var limit = select.value;
document.getElementById(budget).value = limit;
}
```

Your HTML:

```
<select onchange="updatePriceLimit(this,'budget_min')">
<select onchange="updatePriceLimit(this,'budget_max')">
```